# Android webview Toggle div

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I've been trying to figure out how to toggle a Div in Android Webview, like this http://jsfiddle.net/Z9f2b/

this is my Android code but doesn't toggle at all, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? thanks:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String script = "$('#liked').on('click', function() {$('#liked').hide();$('#notliked').show();});$('#notliked').on('click', function() {$('#liked').show();$('#notliked').hide();});";

html = "<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'>1</div><div id='notliked' style="float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red">2</div>";

String summary = "<html>"+script+"<body>"+html+"</body></html>";
wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your javascript in `<script>` tags.

Also, you need to wrap the javascript that you have in a call to `$(window).load` so the handlers get registered when the DOM is ready.

Additionally, you need to link to a version of the JQuery library.

Are you sure you need JQuery for this? You could write it in standard javascript very simply with an `onclick` handler on the div... something like:

```
<div id='liked' style='float:left;display:none; height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue'  onclick="document.getElementById('notliked').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('liked').style.display='none';">1</div>
<div id='notliked' style="float:left;height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red; disply:block" onclick=" document.getElementById('liked').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('notliked').style.display='none';">2</div>
```

Comment: I see, added some more.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading HTML data before insertion of script. Javascript can be inserted after HTML is loaded into web view. This is the better idea. So your code should probably go like this:

```
String summary = "<html><body>"+html+"</body></html>";
wv.loadUrl("about:blank");
wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

and followed by:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:"+script);
```

This will insert javascript onto current web page and you dont even need to take care that where it has to be inserted and how. Webview will take care of it.